# Spectral embedding: interpretation of new dimensions

Tags: clustering, manifold-learning, embeddings

I'm trying to gain an intuition for the 2nd dimension in the spectral embedding of an S-shaped dataset as in [this example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html#manifold): 
[image]

The 1st dimension seems to neatly capture the local similarity between points, but is there a similar physical interpretation for the 2nd dimension? More specifically, why do both red AND blue points show low values for this dimension?

I am wondering whether these dimensions can be interpreted in a similar way as done [for the embedding of hand-written digits](http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~gchen/Math285F15/285%20Final%20Project%20-%20LLE.pdf):

[image]

Comment: Consider the sample in the bottom left of the LLE. It's not thick at all. It didn't capture thickness on the y axis. That was just a pretty story to make it sound cool.

Answer (score 0):

The first dimension yields nthr axis along which to split to get two partitions.

The second dimension is for splitting into 3 or 4 clusters. Try running k-means on this projection with k=3 or k=4 and you should get some decent results.